# Invalid Syntax error due to a colon after an if and statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello Stack community,

I am simply trying to ask the user to enter the number of tickets sold 1-300 so I can use that value to calculate the total revenue from ticket sales based on number of tickets sold and price per ticket. However, my assignment requires to

You can see me attempt that by implementing an "if" "and" statement with a request of input again if the value was not correct.

However, I keep receiving an invalid syntax error as you can see in my screen shot. Is this from my "if" "and" statement just being incorrectly used?

This was done on Python 3.6 on Python IDLE. Here is my code:

def main():

## input request to user

```
resultsA = int(input("Please enter how many seats you sold is section A")
               if resultsA < 1 and resultsA > 300:
               int(input("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 300")


resultsB = int(input("Please enter how many seats you sold is section B")\
               if resultsB is < 1 or > 500:
               int(input("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 500")


resultsC = int(input("Please enter how many seats you sold is section A")
               if resultsC is < 1 or > 200:
               int(input("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 200")
```

## Calculate the input from user

```
finalResultA = 20*resultsA
finalResultsB = 15*resultsB
finalResultsC = 10*resultsC
trulyFinal = finalResultA + finalResultB + finalResultC
```

## print calculation results to user

```
print ("Congratulations, here is your total revenue from tickets:\t", trulyFinal)
```

And here is a screenshot:[image]

Comment: As it says, you have syntax problems. Python is strict about indentation.

Comment: This is a simple syntax error, so I'm going to mark it for closure, but I've answered it below. With that said, I'm upvoting because there's clear effort and an attempt at the problem, a complete example showing where you're having trouble.

Comment: You are missing the closing brackets )

Comment: "Whitespace matters" in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. the contents of `if` statements are indented. Also, each part of an `or` statement needs to be able to 'make sense' on its own. Imagine it as if the two statements are executed entirely separately. Also, you forgot to close your parenthesis for the call to int(). Here's a fixed example.

```
        if resultsB < 1 or resultsB > 500:
            int(input("Please enter a valid number from 1 to 500"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Ares, and I appreciate the kind words. I am still working on tuning which questions and how I ask them on this site.